# What are the Registers pushed to the stack when an Interrupt Occurs

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, kernel, interrupt, cpu-registers

What are the States Saved by the CPU Automatically when an Interrupt Occur ? And in Which order ?

Comment: Why would the order matter? To see what the Linux kernel does, check the actual code that handles this: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S

Comment: What CPU? What mode (real/protected/long)? What kind of interrupt? Usually you just read description of you CPU architecture and use commands it has to generate software interrupt, handle sw/hw interrupt and to return from interrupt. Documentation will also define what was saved by hw and if you want to use some more registers you must save them before use and restore before exit from ISR.

Comment: @osgx: This is tagged x86, so we at least know what architecture.  I can't believe this isn't a duplicate of something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024371/where-does-intel-80386-save-registers, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332517/how-do-the-registers-get-saved-when-a-process-gets-interrupted.  Although maybe one of those should be marked as a dup of this, or not since the 2nd one isn't even x86 specific.

Comment: Peter, you know (with yellow badge on x86 tag) that x86 is not CPU and not architecture, it is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86 "a *family* of backward compatible instruction set architectures". And this family is not best to start studying computer architecture with.

Comment: Yes I'm looking for x86 Architecture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What are the States Saved by the CPU Automatically when an Interrupt Occur ?

Some registers are saved; this set is defined by CPU architecture. It may be saved to stack, to fixed address in memory or in shadow registers. Usually this set of registers is small, if ISR needs more, it may save them by real code, not CPU automatic hardware. (Check link from Cody Gray at "Interrupt entry/exit.")

> And in Which order ?

Order of register saving, when they are pushed to stack is defined by architecture.

For The default architecture, the x86/x86_64 the definition is like (the first link already listed in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38031260/196561 in your previous question, with "*FLAGS, CS, IP" order):

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Advanced_Interrupts & iret documentation http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IRET:IRETD.html

- in real mode, on interrupt hardware pushes FLAGS, push CS, push IP; `iret` instruction will reload them to return to user.
- in protected mode check VM and NT flags in EFLAGS to find how to start and return from interrupt. On hw interrupt (what kind of interrupt you question about) - Check that stack has 10-20 bytes; load SS,eSP,CS:EIP/CS:IP; push "long pointer to old stack", push eflags, push "long pointer to return location"

Actual logic is more complex. There is logic in 386 for entry into interrupt http://intel80386.com/386htm/INT.htm and for iret http://intel80386.com/386htm/IRET.htm ("Operation").

Comment: Thanks man. Is there any documentation for x86 architecture ?

Comment: There is "The documentation" for x86 from intel, "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals" http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html - but it is too complex (it describes many versions of x86 from Intel). You may start from something easier, like MIPS (DLX) or even RISC-V, or from earliest intel, like 386 ([400 pages](http://css.csail.mit.edu/6.858/2015/readings/i386.pdf),1986), 586, Pentium. Or unofficial, like "Unabridged Pentium 4, The: IA32 Processor Genealogy" book (2004). + http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: I saw a line saying "All registers, except for the EFLAGS register which
is restored by the 'IRET' instruction, are preserved by the compiler." in https://gitlab.indel.ch/thirdparty/gcc/commit/5ed3cc7b66af4758f7849ed6f65f4365be8223be and in one of my college courses I had a question asking why *all* registers are saved on the stack on an interrupt. (GCC Convention). But I was not able to find much documentation online; so do some instances save all registers and some save only the ones you mentioned? @osgx